# foreign languages in PSQL data

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin-4

I searched a lot about this, but didn't find anything - How can I support more languages in postgres?

If I upload text in **Hebrew**, it stores it in the database as `??????`.

How can I get Postgres to store my data correctly?

Comment: Search for collation and make sure the data you are inputting is UTF-8 and that UTF-8 is supported through all the intermediaries between submitting the foreign language text and it finally ending up in the database.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways: the collation isn't responsible for that. It's the _encoding_

Comment: Make sure that your client can display Hebrew. Don't use old and unsupported PostgreSQL versions.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql text (and char) columns are (natively) UTF8 and can store any combination of Unicode code points (characters).

If you are seening ????? then your interface used to store or retreive the data is misconfigured.

I did the following using psql on linux (so configured for unicode out of the box)  it's probably harder to do this on windows.

```
jasen=# create table presidents(name text);
CREATE TABLE
jasen=# insert into presidents values ('יצחק "בוז׳י" הרצוג');
INSERT 0 1
jasen=# select * from presidents;
        name        
--------------------
 יצחק "בוז׳י" הרצוג
(1 row)
```

Comment: psql doesn't let me upload the data in the first place with the error: character with byte sequence 0x90 in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"

Comment: try command `set client_encoding to 'utf8';` in psql